# how to iterate through checkbox object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have three checkboxes:-

```
<label>Type:</label>
 <label>one</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" ng-model="a.Type[0]"/>

  <label>two</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" ng-model="a.Type[1]"/>

  <label>three</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="type" ng-model="a.Type[2]"/>
```

These checkboxes are stored in the backend as an array of string.

My value is displaying in:-

```
<li  class="list-group-item"><strong>Type</strong>: <span ng-repeat="values in myArray">{{values}}</span></li>
```

My directive code is:-

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.components')
        .directive('abc', abc);

    abc.$inject = ['$http', '$timeout', 'ApiServices'];

    function abc($http, $timeout, ApiServices) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {

            },

            link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
                scope.a = {};

                $('#abc').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
                    scope.active = false;
                });
                $('#abc').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                    scope.active = true;

                    scope.myArray = [];

                  scope.iterate = function () {
                   for (var key in scope.a.Type) {
                      if (scope.a.Type.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        scope.myArray.push(scope.a.Type[key]);
                      }
                   }
                  };

                  scope.iterate();
            },
            templateUrl: ''
        };
    }

})();
```

Here what I am trying to do is- I want to iterate through 'Type' checkboxes and pushed the values in 'myArray', and then display only the values.

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to do here.  you are showing a `link` function for an unknown directive, and the link function seems to try to iterate *instantly* through an empty object.  Why are you trying to iterate through the array anyway? wouldn't `$scope.a.Type` already be the array you are looking for?  e.g. could you not do `ng-repeat="values in $scope.a.Type"`?

Comment: scope.a.Type in an array of string in the backend but when I am saving the values, they are storing as objects where the key is the index number and value is the name;- one,two,three. So, what I am doing is iteration through that object and getting the values and then push them into 'myArray' and then display the values of array.

Comment: but you aren't (at least not in this code).  I don't know what else your directive is doing, but this link function sets `scope.a = {};` and then immediately tries to iterate through it.

Comment: I will update my code.But here I am only showing the necessary code, function which is iteration through it.

Comment: right, but you aren't showing how `scope.a` goes from being `{}` to having any data in it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, my example below is somewhat similar to what you are looking for:

HTML:

```
  <span>Select Type:</span>
  <div ng-repeat="type in myArray">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="type.value" /> {{type.type}}
  </div>

  <span>Selected Types:</span>
  <div ng-repeat="type in myArray">
    <span ng-show="type.value"> {{type.type}}</span>
  </div>
```

JS:

```
  $scope.a = {};
  $scope.a.Type = ["One","Two","Three"]; // your string array

  $scope.myArray = [];
  $scope.a.Type.forEach(function(item){
    $scope.myArray.push({type: item, value: false }); // create new array to make it selectable via checkbox
  });
```

I guess, you no more need your directive now. The iteration and filtering is done in HTML itself.

I hope this helps.